# Restore Sumatra as default PDF Viewer in RStudio for RMarkdown PDF Knitting

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr, sumatra

I understand I'm late to the party as I have not updated RStudio for a long time. Now I realise that Sumatra PDF viewer is not part of the current RStudio setup anymore for viewing PDFs generated from RMarkdown knitting. I found that people talked about it [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/sumatra-as-viewer-option-is-not-available-in-rstudio-2022-12-0-build-353/155639) and [there](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pdf-not-displayed-after-knitting-a-rmd-file/17548) but haven't seen any solution. Indeed I understood that by default, RStudio wouldn't open the PDFs at all, which irritates me a lot.

So,

- I want to continue viewing RMarkdown knitted PDFs in Sumatra
- immediatly & automatically opened after rendering
- without changing my system default PDF reader (I need that to be Acrobat)

Actually, I wouldn't mind it to be another PDF viewer, however, I really loved the features of Sumatra:

- not requiring to close files before re-rendering
- displaying changes in real-time when rendering
- multiple tabs possible when working on multiple RMarkdown files

As far as I see, the RStudio viewer cannot offer this behavior (no real-time view), and neither can Acrobat (would have to close file before re-rendering).

How have people adapted? This can't be just me.

(Or is this merely a sign of people using Sweave instead? Haven't tried it, but understood it allows for some synctex stuff...)

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Rstudio's forum](https://community.rstudio.com), there isn't really a specific coding question here. If the links to the Rstudio community you provided didnt answer your question, you may want to ask a new one there. Good luck!